# Imploding an array into a string using VB

Tags: vb6

I'm extremely unfamiliar with ancient VB, and I'm trying to figure out the proper commands to concatenate an array (I am assuming it is in array form) into a string with comma separated values.

The values are being provided by a multiselect box, which is being assigned to the areas variable, which is grabbed from the areas select box.

```
dim name
dim from
dim company
dim phone
dim zip
dim message
dim areas

name = Request.Form("name")
from = Request.Form("from")
company = Request.Form("company")
phone = Request.Form("phone")
zip = Request.Form("zip")
areas = Request.Form("areas")
message = Request.Form("message")
```

I want to take areas, and implode it into a string.

What's the command in very old VB to do this?

Comment: VB.NET or VB6? VB.NET is rather new actually. Also, what do you want exactly? Please specify expected result.

Comment: VB6 I believe.

I want to take an array, such as ["item", "item2", "item3", "item4"] and join them into a single string, such as "item, item2, item3, item4"

Comment: I am trying to read the Microsoft example on this - I think this is it, but I'm not quite sure of syntax:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: You need to know for sure, because there will be different solutions. In VB.NET it's [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Syntax: `String.Join(", ", {name, from, company})`. Add as many as you like. But you cannot write like this in VB6, as far as I remember.

Comment: I believe this is VB6. How do I check?

Comment: If your IDE looks very old and plain, it's probably VB6, you could post a screenshot.

Comment: This, to me, looks like ASP classic which actually uses vbscript for the coding language.  Basically, if you open a browser and type a url with a .asp extension, then my assumption is correct.  If my assumption is correct, then areas may already be a comma separated string.

Answer (score 3):

The Join function does also exist in VB6, the syntax is like this:

myString = Join(myArray, ",")

**EDIT:** Note that the array goes before the delimiter. The delimiter is optional, it'll be a space if left empty.

Comment: I didn't ask how to concatenate. I asked how to implode/join an array of string values into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the Join function String.Join(",",array)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VB6, try this:

```
Join(New String() {name, from, company}, ", ")
```

- [Join Function (Visual Basic) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**EDIT:** I know it's a link to VB.NET, but it's the old VB6 function call, it should be compatible with VB6, syntax wise.

Comment: @jac: Thanks for a link. I think the signatures are identical.